# Pull request or Merge request on Google cloud repository

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-repository

I'm having trouble finding where is the Pull the request feature of `Google Cloud Repository`. I need it to setup the project that I'm currently working on for other developers, by having a code review feature.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200647/how-to-do-code-review-for-google-cloud-git-repo.

Comment: @onecompileman Did you find something?

Answer (score 0):

As it is in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/features):

> From a local repository, you can use the standard set of Git commands to interact with the repository in the cloud, including push, pull, clone, and log.

You can use just git to use it. If you click clone and "Manually generated credentials" you will have access to copy git clone statement:

```
git clone https://<link_to_your_google_repo>
```

Than you can use as well

```
git pull https://<link_to_your_google_repo>
```

You can check docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes#pull-from-a-gcp-repository) as well.